# broadcast receiver not working (not getting called)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

So I am registering a broadcast receiver in activity A

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

(directly in the class)

and unregistering it

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
```

.
When I try to call it from activity B

```
Intent finishCheckALoanActivityIntent = new Intent("finish_activity");
            sendBroadcast(finishCheckALoanActivityIntent);
```

(which was started by activity A some time ago (not sure if it matters))
it doesn't finish the activity A. In other words the broadcast receiver doesn't get called. (PS: I am also using finish() in my activity B right after I call the receiver to finish activity A).
I tried debugging it. I've put a breakpoint in the `onReceive` method but the breakpoint doesn't get hit.

Comment: This might sound obvious - do you call `registerReceiver()` with your broadcast? Another thing is, if `onStop()` in Activity A was called, your broadcast receiver is unregistered, so naturally when you send broadcast, it won't be received.

Comment: @Melquiades yes I am calling it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was calling the unregister method inside my onStop activity and when I checked the flow chart again https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity I realised that I am unregistering it before using it so I moved my unregister method calling inside the onDestroy.